# I can't fire terminate callback on exiting iex -S mix

Tags: erlang, elixir

I have an application, which uses `Application` module, and also has an `GenServer` instance running. This `GenServer` module has a `terminate` callback.

The callback works fine if I force some error happen inside server instance, but doesn't fire if I abort the `iex -S mix` session using `Ctrl-C a` or by just closing console window (it should write into some file).

I've tried putting this in `init()`:

```
Process.flag(:trap_exit, true)
```

and also calling `stop/1` in the main module:

```
def stop(state) do
  IO.puts "something" #never shown
  GenServer.stop(pid) #doesn't seem to work
end
```

Comment: See this: [Graceful Shutdown of GenServer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39756769/graceful-shutdown-of-genserver)

Answer (score 2):

From [Saša Jurić’s post](https://elixirforum.com/t/graceful-shutdown-of-genservers/1822/4?u=sheharyarn):

> There is no way of catching abrupt BEAM OS process exits from within. It's a self-defining property: the BEAM process terminates suddenly, so it can't run any code (since it terminated)
>
> Hence, if BEAM is brutally terminated, the callback will not be invoked.

So one solution is to not exit the session using `Ctrl-C`. Instead, you can try calling `:init.stop` which should gracefully shut down the supervision tree.